# yii2 select widget - multiple select in same form

Tags: php, yii2

I need to use the multiple yii2 Select widget in the same form.
For each students i need to show the select widget to select the course. 
When i use multiple select widget in same form only one is appearing
How to do that?

```
$form->field($model, 'course')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
         'data' => ArrayHelper::map(course::find()->asArray()->where(['isActive' => '1'])->all(), 'id', 'name'),
         'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a course...'],
         'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
              ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple add `'multiple'=>true` to options like this

```
$form->field($model, 'course')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
         'data' => ArrayHelper::map(course::find()->asArray()->where(['isActive' => '1'])->all(), 'id', 'name'),
         'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a course...',,'multiple'=>TRUE],
         'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
              ]);
```

Comment: I don't want multi-select. I want 'n' number of dropdown.For each and every student, i need to show a drop down. I need to select course for each student and save ..

Comment: you want to add dynamicly another select?

Comment: yes. Really need help!. At a time i will have 10 students. For each student a drop down will appear and need to select course for all students and save

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic form.there 's an extension about that.please view this link http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo1/create